# Right way to read range header from IHeaderDictionary object

Tags: c#, asp.net, request-headers, actioncontext

I have an `ActionContext` object.

I want to read the `Range` header from the `Request`. What I know is that I can read it like this

```
var rangeHeader = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Range"]
```

but then I have to split the string to get range `from` and `to` values because range header comes like this `byte=100-512`

So is this the right way to read this header from `IHeaderDictonary` or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There's no special helper for that. Of course you can write your own and use it. but anyway you'll need to split it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what might be the "official" way to do it:

Add the following nuget to your project «Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions».

And then do this:

```cs
var range = context.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Range;
```

And you're done :)